# Different instances of the same Rails app, each using a different database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a rails app of which I am running two server instances (different ports, different PID).

```
rails s -p 8081 -P 12345
rails s -p 8082 -P 54321
```

However, I would like each of them to connect to a different mongodb database (for example: `db12345` and `db54321`, respectively).

The problem is that I don't know whether this is possible and if so, how to specify it in my `mongoid.yml` configuration file.

The respective section of my mongoid.yml file, allowing me to use the db12345 database, currently looks like this:

```
development:
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
  sessions:
    default:
      database: **db12345**
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        max_retries: 30
        retry_interval: 1
        timeout: 15
        refresh_interval: 10
```

What I am having trouble with is finding a way to link each instance of the same rails app to the (different) database it should use. Is this even meant to be dealt with in `mongoid.yml`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this via environment variables. Have your apps launched in this manner:

```
DBNAME=db12345 rails s -p 8081 -P 12345
DBNAME=db54321 rails s -p 8082 -P 54321
```

Then just refer to this var in `mongoid.yml`, with a sane default:

```
  sessions:
    default:
      database: <%= ENV['DBNAME'] || 'db12345' %>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! There is also a dba stackexchange question related to this. I don't know how this works, but if you want you can answer this question over there as well. Here's the link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142445/different-instances-of-the-same-rails-app-each-using-a-different-mongo-database

Comment: @MT: crossposting is discouraged on stackexchange. But this question does look like a valid DBA stuff, so I'm going to post the answer there too.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know! I was thinking others might be looking for an answer over there. In any case, thank you for your help!